# Repeater to xls exports my repeater buttons too into the xls

Tags: asp.net, repeater, export-to-excel, xls, export-to-csv

i Have repeater connected to my database and i want to export its data into xls file .
i was able to do that ,except that since my repater contains a control button to manipulate the row (deleting) my xls is rendered with this button.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"   EnableTheming="true"onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="datatable fullwidthpercent"> 
               <tr>
                   <td>ID</td>                     
                   <td> Nom</td>                             
                   <td>Prénom</td>                              
                   <td>Email</td>                      
                   <td>Adresse</td>
                   <td>Ville</td>
                   <td>Tél</td>
               </tr>

    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>

               <tr>
                   <td><%# Eval("id") %></td>                           
                   <td><%# Eval("nom") %></td>                         
                   <td><%# Eval("prenom") %></td>                         
                   <td><%# Eval("email") %></td>
                   <td><%# Eval("adresse") %></td>
                   <td><%# Eval("ville") %></td>
                   <td><%# Eval("tel") %></td>
                   <td><asp:Button ID="Btn1" runat="server" CommandArgument= ' <%# Eval("id") %> ' Text="Eliminer" OnClick = "buttonEliminer_click" ></asp:Button></td>                   
               </tr>                  

        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="6"><hr /></td>
        </tr>
        </SeparatorTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
           </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Code Behind :

```
  protected void ButtonExporter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Gagnants.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        Repeater1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write("<table>");
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.Write("</table>");
        Response.End();

    }
```

overriding method to get over the form balise problem when rendering a repeter with inside control :

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
           server control at run time. */
    }
```

and i get this at the output xls : 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to implement code that sets the button's (`Btn1`) visibility to false. When a server control's visibility is set to false, it is not rendered on the page.

I would suggest the following code changes:

First, create a page-level variable that determines what you are rendering to. You want to set this to default to `true`, since that is your default status (rendering to the screen)

```
private bool _IsRenderForScreen = true;
public property bool IsRenderForScreen {
   get {
      return this._IsRenderForScreen;
   }
   set {
      this._IsRenderForScreen = value;
   }
}
```

Then, in the `ButtonExporter_Click` method, set this variable to false:

```
this.IsRenderForScreen = false;
```

Then hook into the repeater's `ItemDataBound` event:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" ...
```

Then add the following method to handle the event:

```
public void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
        if(!this.IsRenderForScreen) {
            ((Button)e.Item.FindControl("Btn1")).Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

HTH. Let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: Ok, i did Understand the idea, unfortunately i still have the same issue the button is rendered .
I think that the HtmlRendering method renders everything in the page even if it is invisible.
i'm still thinking about an accurate solution but no clue till now .
Thank you though for your answer I really apprecciated your method and learned a lot from it !

Comment: Sir i'm telling you you are the Best! 
your solution worked great when i refreshed my repeater bind in my xls_exporting button action [ButtonExporter] (of course i previously sat the property to false) .
this way each time i wanna export i'm rendering a repeater with no button !
Thank you very much Again !